# Why error bar doesn't show up in ggpubr::ggbarplot even after adding add='mean_se'

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggpubr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(genes = c(
  "Ccl2", "Bar", "Wnt5a", "Ccl2", "Ccl2",
  "Bar", "Ccl2", "Wnt5a", "Wnt5a", "Bar", "Ccl2", "Bar", "Wnt5a",
  "Bar", "Ccl2", "Ccl2", "Ccl2", "Bar", "Ccl2", "Wnt5a", "Ccl2",
  "Bar", "Bar", "Wnt5a", "Bar", "Ccl2", "Ccl2", "Ccl2", "Bar",
  "Bar", "Ccl2", "Wnt5a", "Ccl2", "Wnt5a", "Bar", "Bar", "Bar",
  "Ccl2", "Bar", "Bar", "Wnt5a", "Wnt5a", "Wnt5a", "Wnt5a", "Ccl2",
  "Wnt5a", "Bar", "Bar", "Bar", "Bar", "Ccl2"
), gexp = c(
  0,
  2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
  2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 13, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 10, 0, 2, 3, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 3, 11
), Treat = c(
  "Non_Treat", "Non_Treat",
  "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat", "Foo", "Saline", "Non_Treat", "Foo",
  "Saline", "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat", "Foo",
  "Foo", "Saline", "Non_Treat", "Foo", "Foo", "Saline", "Non_Treat",
  "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat", "Foo", "Foo",
  "Foo", "Foo", "Saline", "Non_Treat", "Non_Treat", "Non_Treat",
  "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat", "Saline", "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat",
  "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Non_Treat", "Non_Treat", "Non_Treat",
  "Non_Treat", "Foo"
), partition = c(
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), cell_name = c(
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP",
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP",
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP",
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP",
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP",
  "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP", "SaP"
), Qux_status = c(
  "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux+", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux+",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux+", "Qux+", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-", "Qux+", "Qux-", "Qux+", "Qux-", "Qux-", "Qux-",
  "Qux-"
), sname = structure(c(
  4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L,
  6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L,
  6L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L,
  6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L
), .Label = c(
  "Qux+.Non_Treat",
  "Qux+.Saline", "Qux+.Foo", "Qux-.Non_Treat", "Qux-.Saline",
  "Qux-.Foo"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I'm using **[ggpubr::ggbarplot](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggbarplot.html)** to make the barpolot with error bar.
With this code

```
ggpubr::ggbarplot(df, x = "sname", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se")
```

I expect the error bar to show up.
But it didn't

[image]
And it gave me this message:

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
object 'mean_se_' of mode 'function' was not found
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an IT call person, does closing R (and the R-studio project if applicable) and opening  it again fix this? Updating R if it's old? I've seen some similar odd issues that where gone that way, implying a problem in the R run time somehow.

Comment: @kabanus Tried that. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @scamander Have you tried using `mean_se_` instead of `mean_se` ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is the type of thing that maybe a local thing on your machine, where the only remedies are reinstalling packages/R. Wait a couple of days and see if anyone else had something similar, but if not you may have to start re-installing thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should not happen, but the simple fix is to load the package `ggpubr` first `library(ggpubr)`. I do not know why but it works on my machine.

```
library(ggpubr)
ggbarplot(df, x = "sname", y = "gexp", add = "mean_se")
```

[image]