# ggpubr can't find 'mean_se' unless ggpubr is attached via library()

Tags: r, ggplot2, devtools, r-package, ggpubr

**Summary of problem:** When I try to add summary stats to a ggpubr plot via the "add" parameter, ggpubr can't find the summary stat functions (*example code below*). For instance, if I am trying to add error bars with `add="mean_se"` I get an error message and no error bars.

***Unsatisfactory* solution:** Attaching ggpubr by calling `library(ggpubr)` *would* fix this problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67966665/4104189).

**Why the above solution is unsatisfactory:** I am developing a package, and so would like to avoid attaching other packages via calls to library() - my understanding is that this is best practice, to avoid polluting the namespace with things the user might not have anticipated would get loaded.

**MY QUESTION:** Is there some way to get ggpubr to find `mean_se` without attaching the package?

Example code (in an .R file in my package):

```
make.plot = function(){
  utils::data("iris")
  ggpubr::ggbarplot(
    data = iris,
    x = "Species",
    y = "Sepal.Length",
    add = "mean_se")
}
```

Example output:

```
> devtools::load_all(".")
# i Loading MyPackage
> make.plot()
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
# object 'mean_se_' of mode 'function' was not found
```

One thing that *should* work, but doesn't, is passing "ggpubr::mean_se_" as the `add` argument. This avoids the error message, but produces an incorrect plot. The plot should look like this:

[image: Desired plot]

But passing "ggpubr::mean_se_" instead produces:
[image]

**Additional weirdness:** If I *ever* add a call to load ggpubr, build MyPackage with `devtools::load_all(".")`, and run it, then the above code *never* fails until I quit and reload RStudio, even if I delete the call `library(ggpubr)` from my package and build it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating a package you can ensure that `mean_se_` is in the search path by importing it in your function.

If you use roxygen you can add the tag `@importFrom ggpubr mean_se_`:

```r
#' @importFrom ggpubr mean_se_
make.plot = function(){
  utils::data("iris")
  ggpubr::ggbarplot(
    data = iris,
    x = "Species",
    y = "Sepal.Length",
    add = "mean_se")
}
```

Then you run `devtools::document()` and run your function, and your output should look like this:

[image: a plot]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the way the `add` parameter is handled inside `ggpubr`, it is actually matched as a string to one of the summary functions. It seems that the summary functions need to be on the search path when `ggbarplot` is called.

The easiest way round this is to copy the function over to your own package namespace:

```r
mean_se_ <- ggpubr::mean_se_

make.plot = function(){
  utils::data("iris")
  ggpubr::ggbarplot(
    data = iris,
    x = "Species",
    y = "Sepal.Length",
    add = "mean_se_")
}

make.plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This *should* work, but unfortunately does not. While it prevents ggpubr from complaining, the plot it produces is incorrect - it has a bunch of slices in each bar, rather than adding error bars as desired. Strangely, this is different behavior than what "mean_se_" does if you call `library(ggpubr)` first. I've updated my question to show the desired output.

Comment: @Azura'sStarfish I see. Check out my update.